# how to get Firebase Analytics App Instance Id for Web App?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to log `purchase` event via [Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). if I read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase#required_parameters), it is said that I must have `app_instance_id` so I can send the data from our backend to GA4 server.

we are using Vue and [Firebase Nuxt](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started/) for our web app, but unfortunately, as you can see from the image below, I can't find a method to get `app_instance_id`

[image]

so how to get `app_instance_id` for web app in Firebase for web app? is it not available yet? please help

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, for now the `app_instance_id` is not available for web. please read the full explanation in Github from Firebase Analytics repo maintainer [in here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6881#issuecomment-1353517337)

and for now, from the event builder measurement procotol web, it seems that we can't use Firebase for web client, we have to use gtag instead. Firebase is only for mobile. the JSON body and query parameters will be different if you send event via gtag or via Firebase

https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/

[image]

this is [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#required_parameters) to send event via gtag